# Get threaded comments number

Tags: comments, threading, children

I'm using Greg's Threaded Comment Numbering plugin to number the comments. Actually I'm displaying a number beside of each parent comment (no threaded comments numbers). I have 2 problems that I have already tried to solve, but without results:

- I am displaying the top comment with a different layout, I need to start the numbering from #2. seems an easy task but I didn't find the way modifying the plugin code.
- Display the total number of threaded comments for each comment that has threads.

Example:

COMMENT 1

------------1.1

------------1.2

------------1.3

total threaded comments = 3

COMMENT 2

------------2.1

------------2.2

total threaded comments = 2

etc.....

I am already using the code below to get the total number of parents. I can also get the children but it is the total, I need to display the number of each comment children as in the example

```
$number_of_parents = c_parent_comment_counter($post->ID);
$number_of_children = $post->comment_count - $number_of_parents;
```

Thanks!

EDIT: as requested here is the wp_list_comments callback function. Sorry for the mess, I am not a programmer, will clean the code when the work is finished :)

```
## Function: Basic Callback Function From WP Codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_comments), January 2009
function gtcn_basic_callback($comment, $args, $depth) {
// no changes here except that we have added in the call to gtcn_comment_numbering
   $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment; 


   ?>
   <li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
   <?php   if( empty( $comment->comment_parent ) ) { //if the comment does not have a parent, then it is L1?>
            <div class="linguetta-posizione"><?php  echo gtcn_comment_numbering($comment->comment_ID, $args); 

            ?></div>        
                <?php   }
         ?>

     <div id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
      <div class="comment-author vcard">
        <div class="comment-barra-user">

            <div class="comment-avatar">
            <?php if( empty( $comment->comment_parent ) ) { ?><?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='60'); ?><?php } else { ?><?php echo get_avatar($comment,$size='30'); ?><?php } ?></div>
            <div class="comment-username"><?php printf(('<cite class="fn">%s</cite> '), get_comment_author_link()) ?><br class="clear"/>
                <?php if( empty( $comment->comment_parent ) ) { ?><div id="comment-container-points">
                    <div class="comment-points"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ico-points.png" /><a>3333</a></div><div class="comment-level"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/ico-level.png" /><a>livello</a></div>
                </div>      <?php } else { ?><?php } ?>         
            </div>
            <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { if( empty( $comment->comment_parent ) ) {?>
            <div class="comment-votazione"><h2>Vota la risposta:</h2>

            <?php    { //if the comment does not have a parent, then it is L1
                    if(function_exists(ckrating_display_karma)) { ckrating_display_karma(); }
                    }
         ?> </div>
            <?php }} else { 

                if( empty( $comment->comment_parent ) ) { ?>
                <div class="comment-votazione"><h2>Registrati per votare</h2>

                 </div>
            <?php }}  ?> 


        </div><!-- end BARRA USER -->

    <br class="clear"/>

      </div>
      <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') : ?>
         <em><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation.') ?></em>
         <br />
      <?php endif; ?>


      <?php comment_text() ?>

      <div class="reply">
         <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge( $args, array('reply_text' => 'COMMENTA LA RISPOSTA', 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth']))) ?>
      </div><div class="comment-meta commentmetadata"><?php if( empty( $comment->comment_parent ) ) { ?>Risposta inserita<?php } else { ?> Commento inserito <?php } ?>
            <?php echo time_ago_comment(); ?><?php edit_comment_link(('- modifica'),'  ','') ?></div>

     </div></li>

<?php
} // end basic callback function
```

Comment: Please post the code of your `wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'your_function' ) );` callback function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// inside your callback function:
static $ancestors = null;
$parent = (int) $comment->comment_parent;

// Modify INITIAL VALUE here:
$init_val = (int) 1;

$is_child = false;
if ( $parent > (int) 0 )
{
    $is_child = true;
    $ancestors[] = $parent;
    $child_counter = count( $ancestors ) + $init_val;
}
/*
 * Only needed in case you want to reset the counter if the current comment has no children
else
{
    $ancestors = $child_counter = null;
}
*/

// This shows the number of the current reply counter
if ( $is_child ) 
    printf( __( 'This is the child number: ', TEXTDOMAIN ), $child_counter );
```

Comment: Thanks kaiser, tried but does not output anything.

Comment: @Andycap - Where exactly did you place that? It's close to what i use in my callback myself, so i know that it does work smoothly. Could you post your updated (and please: cleaned) callback function? Tante grazie!

Comment: Oh, and you need to replace `TEXTDOMAIN` with your textdomain string/constant/var or delete to avoid an ugly error.

Comment: Got it, thanks it's working! But maybe we had a misunderstanding: the code is counting each child, what I need is just to display the total number, example: "This comment has XX child comments". For ancestors: I need to count them but starting from 2 (ancestor + 1). Perhaps both could be solved modifying your code so I can get rid of the numbering plugin! Thanks

Comment: See update with init value and uncommented `else`. And please don't forget to vote and mark as solution if so. This will give you some pretty good karma :)

Comment: good code, but it stills shows number of each childern, not displaying the number of childes for each parent.

Comment: @sandblue Read the comments in code and improve upon it. :)

Comment: @kaiser `$init_val = 0;` gets the correct count of the number of replies for each parent comment. The problem is we also get every value of `$child_counter` less than the highest value,  for example `if ( $comment->comment_parent ) 
echo $child_counter;` - if we have three replies to a parent comment it will read "123", if there are 20 replies "1234...20". Pretty near getting this to work, only need to get the last/highest value of $child_counter for each parent comment. Any idea how?

Comment: @psot Merry Christmas! Please see the date of this answer. If it still works (don't know as this is for a pretty old WP version), but if it does, then the rest is just plain PHP Array and/or String handling.