# Numbering only parent comments

Tags: comments

I am actually displaying a number beside my comments putting `$counter = 0;` before wp_list_comments in comments.php and

```
global $counter;
$counter++;
```

inside the comments callback function in functions.php

Now this is working fine, but since I'm using threaded comments, my numbers are looking strange (1,4,10,14) because it's counting also the child comments.

Is there a way to count only parent comments (1,2,3,4,5...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the comment has a parent and only count if not:

```
global $counter;
if ($comment->parent == 0){
  $counter++; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this but it's still counting parents and childs.

Comment: Then there must be something else since this simple code can only count parents,  paste your code here for us

Comment: Sorry, I messed up something with the echo, it's working.

Answer (score 1):

This Q is close to a dublicate of [this Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16867/get-threaded-comments-number/16871#16871), that you already asked. The only thing you have to make different, is that you switch the content of the if/else statement.

Comment: Yes Kaiser, you're right, but I got rid of the plugin and I was looking for a really simple solution. Forgive me, I'm not very smart with programming, I'm a designer, but trying to learn something more. thanks